# How to keep cell blank until data is entered in vlook up

Tags: windows

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,$AS$1:$AT$202,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

I want the blank to stay until I enter a 
value in the drop down column.

Comment: Is this question about not showing the NA?

Comment: can you provide more explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by adding an IF to check if the dropdown cell has info, or alterantively if the result is an error or not.

Your formula would become:

```
=IF(H2="";"";VLOOKUP(H2,$AS$1:$AT$202,2,FALSE))
```

Note that the IF portion is the following:

```
=IF(H2="";"";       VLOOKUP(H2,$AS$1:$AT$202,2,FALSE)      )
```

It means, if H2 is containing "", then "" is returned. If not, then perform the VLookup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IFERROR`

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(H2, $A$1:$B$4,1,FALSE),"")
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. Whoo hoo!!! My work book is complete.